# Error compiling a C++ pgm on an IBM z/OS system using the XL compiler: CCN5258 (S)

Tags: enums

Good day.
Preface to say I'm new to C++ and appreciate any help!

I'm having a problem compiling a C++ pgm on an IBM z/OS system using the XL compiler.  However, I don't think this is platform/system specific??

The error message I'm getting is:
CCN5258 (S) A return value of type "STATUS" cannot be initialized with an expression of type "int".

In my hdr file:

enum STATUS {FAILURE,SUCCESS};       // Global

class EXPORT MyClass {
public:
...
STATUS myFunction();
...
}

In my CPP pgm:

STATUS myFunction() {
...
return SUCCESS;     <<<----- Compiler error CCN5258 flagged for this statement
}

Experimenting, I found that if I change STATUS type to INT and change myFunction to: int myFunction() it compiles successfully.

TYIA
Neil